# Faster outputs with a different format specifier

Tags: c, format-specifiers

In the below sample

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main(void) {
        int t,n,x,i;
        long int num;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--){
            scanf("%d",&n);num=0;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&x);
            num=num+(x*pow(10,(n-i)));
            }
            printf("%ld\n",num);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The sample takes a time of 0.03s for a set of input.
When I changed the format specifier from `%ld` to `%d`, in printf, the sample took a time of 0.02s for the same value and number of input.
 

 
In both cases, `num` is of type `long int` and is evaluated in that form.
Why does this happen, even though the result is of the same size in both cases ?

Comment: So you did not change `num` to match the `%d` format specifier? To get realistic timings you need to repeat the operation a large number of times, so tnat it takes several seconds.

Comment: @WeatherVane num remains to be of type `long int` in both cases

Comment: What are `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(int)`? They are both `4` on my machine.

Comment: There are no timings in the code. So the input must have been redirected from a file, and there is a lot more going on that just the printf. Your test is not rigorous and is far too short to have any validity.

Comment: @WeatherVane `int` is 2 bytes and `long` is 4

Comment: `%ld` is one character longer than `%d` so takes longer to process ;) and that processing is done at runtime and not by the compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane The input size is the same for both cases, and the type of `num` is the same too, in both cases. So why would printing take longer time? since the result is of the same size in both cases ?

Comment: I just said, the *text* `"%ld"` is one character longer than the *text* `"%d"` and it has to be interpreted by `printf` on every call. It is also converting 4 bytes and not 2. `printf` takes no notice that there are 2 unused bytes in the second case. It does not know what you gave it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Would `%ld` interpret a number the same way `%d` would for a number within the `int` range ?

Comment: No, `printf` *thinks* the variables are different size. 4 bytes takes more processing than 2, particularly if the processor is 16-bit.

Comment: @WeatherVane Alright. Could I get a reference to how the variables are processed ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Concerning "and it has to be interpreted by `printf` on every call." is not specified by C.  Good compilers will analyze the format and may emit the same code for `scanf("%d",&x);` as `x = _read_int_from_stdin();` or some other equivalent build in function.  Repeated interpretation of a constant format is not _required_ at run-time - although that _could_ be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exact are your timing results? If you used the `time` command, it only gives you two decimals, so the difference between `0.03` and `0.02` is not significant (for example, it might actually have been `0.02500001` and `0.02499999` before rounding). Use a longer input and repeat the test several times, averaging the result, and looking at the standard deviation to see if the difference is statistically significant.

That said, depending on your platform, `int` and `long int` may just as well have the same size, making the two equivalent. If they are not, then it depends on whether the C library on your platform actually uses a different routine to parse long ints compared to normal ints. I would expect that internally it always uses the same routine, the one for the longest possible integer size, and just casts the result to the requested type.

Comment: I have used an online ide to get the time taken and execute the program. Does that make a difference ?

Comment: Plus, the type of `num` during the execution of the program is the same. Everything is the same other than the printf format specifier. So how does printing the same result, using 2 different format specifiers make a difference in the time taken?

Comment: Yes ! I checked the assembly code of the 2 instances and it turns out the one with `%ld` in printf needs greater processing than the one with `%d`, even though the only difference within the 2 codes is the printf. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> When I changed the format specifier from %ld to %d ...

... is *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
long int num;
...
printf("%d\n",num);  // mis-matched specifier and data type.
```

Even though OP may be received expected results with un-posted inputs, the performance comparison is [moot](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/moot) due to UB.

---

When performing timing comparisons, the data set, the order of tests (due to memory caching) and many factors contribute. For a good analysis, post code that does not have *undefined behavior*  and when run, shows the difference unto itself.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is UB but, I actually wanted to understand this undefined behavior. Is it possible to perhaps get an explanation or even a reference to how this undefined behavior works ?

Comment: Yes.  Examine the code created by the compiler is the most direct and certainly correct answer - or are you looking for guesses?  In that case, this post lacks needed information like platform/processor, compiler, version and data used for a good guess.

Comment: Yes ! I got it ! I considered the assemble code of the two separate codes, and  found the difference. Supposedly the code, where `%d` is considered, makes use of `.lc0` only, whereas, the code where `%ld` is considered, makes use of `.lc0` and `.lc2`. So basically, considers greater memory. Thank you so much for the help ! But, G. Sliepen was right and I'd have to accept his answer, since I can acccept only one.